# jQuery: attach event to 2 forms only in page with 3 forms

Tags: jquery, forms, events

I have a page with 3 forms, every form has it's unique id. I also have two scripts, one should be invoked with two forms but not the third and another only with the third. I can attach the script to the third only by selecting it like this:

```
$("#third_form")
```

but how do I attach the other script to only the first and second form?
I tried to attach it to all forms like this:

```
$('form')
```

but obviously then this is attached to the `#third_form` too so I though I can check what form is submitted by

```
var form = $(this);

if (form != '#third_form'){ ... }
```

but it's not working.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use comma separator `,` to pass multiple selector :

```
$('#first_form,#second_form')
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#first_form,#second_form').on('submit', function(){
  alert('First or Second_form');
})
$('#third_form').on('submit', function(){
  alert('Third form');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='first_form'>
  <input type='submit' value='First form submit'/>
</form>
<br/>
<form id='second_form'>
  <input type='submit' value='Second form submit'/>
</form>
<br/>
<form id='third_form'>
  <input type='submit' value='Third form submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: no this doesn't work, error: #first_form, #second_form. submit is not a function

Comment: I don't need to submit the two forms at the same time, it's either first or second, with your code the script is not invoked.

Comment: I tried your code what happens is I get the json on screen and the rest of the script that updates my page is not running. While everything works if I check the $(form).attr('id') to be != 'third_form' as in @gdfgdfg answer.

Comment: You could use @gdfgdfg answer but mine also should works and submit just the form that encapsulate it...

Comment: I'll try your suggested solution again and report what happens.

Comment: Actually now it's working, I don't know what mistake I made earlier as it seems I wrote the same exact thing as before. Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#first_form, #second_form')
```

Comment: no this doesn't work, error: #first_form, #second_form. submit is not a function

Comment: tried again and it's working, maybe I had some syntax error, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(form).attr('id') != 'third_form'){ ... }
```

$('form'), you need to select the id value and compare it with another selector, but not the entire object which is - $(form).

Answer (score 0):

> var form = $(this);
>
> if (form != '#third_form'){ ... }
>
> but it's not working. Any idea?

Because form is a jQuery object and you want compare it against a string. So, you can do:

> if (this.id != '#third_form'){ ... }

You could use "event.target.id"  or "this.id" like in:

```js
$(function () {
  $('form').on('click', function(e) {
    // or this.id
    if (e.target.parentNode.id == 'third_form' || e.target.id == 'third_form') {
      alert('third_form');
    } else {
      alert('one of the first two forms')
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form id="first_form">
    first_form<br>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<form id="second_form">
    second_form<br>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<form id="third_form">
    third_form<br>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Comment: what's the difference in checking that attr('id') of the form being submitted is different from 'third_form' ?

Comment: @Chriz74 When it's possible I prefer to use directly the event.target.id or this.id because in any case the info is exactly there.